# HTML5 Equivalent of jQuery flip plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, css

How to I duplicate the behavior of [this plugin](http://lab.smashup.it/flip) with straight JS/CSS?

Screenshot from site:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: One good place to start would be to read the source code of the plugin itself ...

Comment: And then read the source code of jQuery.

Comment: Another option for you could be to use CSS3 Transformations. http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/ depending on your browser requirements.

Comment: By the time that CSS3 transitions are main stream, we'll be writing all our CSS in JavaScript 2 as states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can use CSS3 Transformations to achieve the effect you are looking for

Here's an [article from Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/10-css3-properties-you-need-to-be-familiar-with/) which demonstrate a technique using CSS3 Transformations. If you wish, skip to the final project part. [The demo](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/855_cssProperties/flipper.html) looks more or less similar to the plugin's demos.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific additional support in HTML5 for this. Just copy the code from jQuery and the plugin. Or use jQuery directly.